# link_to nested resource route can't find ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The link_to in my user name is creating an error and I don't know why.

**Error:**

Couldn't find StripeAccount without an ID

**Controller:**
this is inside a separate controller from the StripeAccount controller

```
def settings
    @user = current_user.id
    @stripe_account = StripeAccount.find(params[:stripe_account_id])
  end
```

I have tried "@stripe_account = StripeAccount.find(params[:id])" with the same error

**View:**

```
<%= link_to user_stripe_account_path(@user, @stripe_account) %>
```

I have tried using @stripe_account.id, etc.

**Models:**

```
stripe_account::

  belongs_to :user, optional: true

user::

  has_one :stripe_account
```

**Routes:**

```
  resources :users do
    resources :stripe_accounts
  end
```

**Error when i try loading the /settings page:**

Here's the CMD from when I use: @stripe_account = StripeAccount.find(params[:stripe_account_id])

```
app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:18:in `settings'
Started GET "/settings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-17 06:27:04 -0500
Processing by DashboardController#settings as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:17
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find StripeAccount without an ID):

app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:18:in `settings'
```

When i use @stripe_account = StripeAccount.find(params[:id])

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find StripeAccount without an ID):

app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:18:in `settings'
Started GET "/settings" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-17 06:28:21 -0500
Processing by DashboardController#settings as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:17
Completed 404 Not Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find StripeAccount without an ID):

app/controllers/dashboard_controller.rb:18:in `settings'
```

What am i doing incorrectly?

The only issue i can think of that may be happening is rails/ruby is finding the API ID from stripe_account, which contains a bunch of information from stripe... if so, is there a way i can specifically state using the ID from the table?

Comment: How're your routes defined (`bundle exec rails routes`).

Comment: https://pastebin.com/QjjBD4A1 thats my routes link

Comment: figured it out.... needed to be     @stripe_account = StripeAccount.find_by(params[:id])
 ...... key "find_by"  ...tried so many combos lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do `@stripe_account = current_user.stripe_account` if you wan't to set the variable to the current_user's stripe account (you have no id param on the request). And I recommend you to use `@user = current_user` or `@user_id = current_user.id` since it's confusing to read a variable named `@user` that has an integer value.

When you define "StripeAccount belongs_to User", by default (it's the convention) ActiveRecord looks for a `user_id` column on `stripe_accounts` table.

I'd recommend you to read this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html. It explains all types of associations and you can configure your associations even if they are not conventional (different class names, no `_id` column, etc).

Comment: this might sound stupid, but i read that page twice... until i see code in action - i won't be able to wrap my head around it.  most of the time i learn, i look up example code along with the reference such as the website you linked.  then ill create my own test app, add it, see what happens.. delete things here, there , check the website to see what happened, etc.

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, i got one way to work.  I'm not sure how efficient this is and i will explore more options.

This ended up working how i wanted to:

```
@stripe_account = StripeAccount.find_by(params[:id])
```

The key was using ".find_by" and not ".find".  This allows the link_to to operate and goes to the right location.

Comment: `.find` should work, on your question you used `.find(params[:stripe_account_id])` when the param was actually just `:id`. Also it's not clear what does it have to do with nested routes since you are using `dashboard/settings` route that's not a nested route.

Comment: That didn't work either.  This is all taking place in a view separate to the StripeAccount view.   its in view/dashboard so i'm using dashboard controller.  is there another way to go about it?

Comment: You should be able to do `@stripe_account = current_user.stripe_account` if you wan't to set the variable to the current_user's stripe account (you have no id param on the request). And I recommend you to use `@user = current_user` or `@user_id = current_user.id` since it's confusing to read a variable named `@user` that has an integer value.

Comment: Works! So is that basically saying (@stripe_account = current_user.stripe_account) .... ".stripe_account" is the associated table to the current user? Ruby just figures it out? --- since i have user_id in the stripe_account table?

Comment: ill give you the green check if you create a response to the post